# Magento2: How to disabled coupon code programmatically from the cart and checkout page?

Tags: magento2, programmatically, coupon-codes, remove

I want to disabled coupon code programmatically from the cart and checkout page if the condition is true.

Please help me.

Comment: You mean to remove coupon code section from cart page and checkout page ?

Comment: @user55548 Yes, I want to remove coupon code if the condition is true programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Remove coupon box from:

**1. Cart Page**

Create new file in your module {Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.coupon" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2. Checkout Page**

Create new file in your module {Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I want to remove coupon code if the condition is true programmatically.

Comment: Which condition is true?